# Is it possible to shorten the flue/chimney of a range hood?

Tags: range, microwave-oven, hood

We are replacing our OTR microwave with a more efficient hood.

The microwave hung under a top cabinet, with about 62" of clearance from stove to bottom of top cabinet.

Is there a way to shorten the flue of a range hood if it comes with one slightly longer than permits by height?

Comment: 62 inches ? that's 5 feet 2 inches from top of range to bottom of cabinet. Is your cabinet only accessible with a step ladder? Are sure you need shorter ducting?

Comment: Sorry! 3’2” my mistake. Phone changed it for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the hood. Some come with a telescopic shroud, to go *bigger*, but not smaller. Check the dimensions on the box. Whatever the small dimension is, has to be able to fit.

Or open the box to see how much of the shroud you could cut off, having grabbed an elbow from another isle in the store to see the ultimate clearance requirements when assembled. Flexible might save you an extra inch or so, but is ideally avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The range hood will attach securely to the bottom of the cabinet just like the microwave did. There will be two mounting options. You can either vent out the side of the house or up through the roof. You can buy duct fittings for either option when you purchase the hood. You shouldn't have to cut any of the ductwork. You can also buy range hoods that work with a charcoal filter (ductless).